# Could Wordpress have lazy-loading queries? Or is it limitation of PHP?

Tags: php, iterator, wordpress

There's an interesting comparison of the functional Clojure language vs Python for lazy-loading and similar functions [here](http://www.pixelmonkey.org/2014/11/02/clojonic?imm_mid=0c681e&cmp=em-prog-na-na-newsltr_20141108). It got me thinking - is there no comparable feature in PHP? For example, when you do a Wordpress query:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( ... )
```

You immediately have the full array of posts `$loop->posts` and (unless I'm mistaken), that array was fully created on WP_Query constructor. In Java, or Python with iterator, you generally would have a database-cursor-iterator that you would call a get-next function to get the next item as needed.

Is the reason Wordpress doesn't do this based on lack of such iterator notion in PHP, or some other reason?

Comment: well php is server side only, how would you call the next item from the client side? You could use ajax alright but you also have the stateless problem so hence session vars, cookies, db entries etc. Dont forget wp_query is also customizable in terms of pagination, types, etc so its up to you how you run it.

Comment: @David PHP isn't "server-side only", it can be run as a scripting language locally like Python or Bash. You have a point, I wonder if its web-centric stateless design is a reason for this.

Comment: define  locally? When i say server side only, i mean its not possible to execute a php script in a client browser without ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that yes you can iterate over a database cursor in PHP. The `WP_Query()` class is a convenience library to wrap this up and make it easy for you to use the filters/parameters provided in that API. Ultimately WordPress uses the `mysql_*` extensions (deprecated) on current version and older installs, however when using newer version of PHP it uses `mysqli` as the underlying database connector.

In regards to WP_Query, its [`__construct()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3919) calls [`query()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3814) which then calls [`get_posts()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3814). On [line 3554](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3454) it uses the `global $wpdb` object to call [`get_results()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1933). This ultimately calls the [`query()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1525) method, (and `_do_query()` internally) and finally iterates over the results on [line 1615](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1615).

You are free to use the `WP_Query()`, `$wpdb`, or even `mysql_*`/`mysqli` to handle your database code in WordPress, listed from a higher level of abstraction to lower. Things like protection from SQL injections are provided by the higher level classes, but you have more control going to a lower level class.

The possibility of using more efficient yield statements has been discussed [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229982/why-not-yield-iterable-in-posts-interface), and apparently part of the resistance is that WP needs to work *everywhere* even on *ancient* systems - the same reason it is using jQuery 1.x series that works with very old IE versions.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good overview of db in Wordpress but I was wondering why the design choice was made to do it as such in Wordpress. Actually it looks like PHP5 was released July 2004 with [Iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and Wordpress was in development well before that, that may be one reason for the way it was structured?

Comment: WordPress started out strictly as a blogging platform and has since matured into a full blown CMS. Classes like `WP_Query` are supposed to make it easier to work with than having to know SQL, and all of the changes to WordPress take backwards compatibility into consideration. Because you aren't forced to use these classes they aren't really limiting you, so why change what's not broken.